# php artisan command is not working suddenly

Tags: php, laravel

After getting pull request my `php artisan migrate command` inside a laravel project through the following error:

```
 [ErrorException]
  Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ?: d` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ?: d` or `a ? b : (c ?: d)`
```

I suspect this may cause for PHP version. I install 7.2. But problem exist. Any idea?

Comment: I think you should use newer version of PHP.

Comment: @tirtakeniten if something is deprecated in the version they are using it will most likely be more of an issue in newer versions

Answer (score 0):

if you use if statement like this a ? b : c ?: d put parentheses to show the strength of the statements. Like this (a ? b : c) ?: d